# Error "Unable to parse response, not valid JSON" when extracting media from an Instagram handle

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using `python-instagram` library to try and extract the last 10 media posted by an Instagram user. I'm using the `user_recent_media` endpoint for the same as follows:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = <my_access_token>

api = InstagramAPI(client_secret='XXXX', access_token=access_token[0])
usr = api.user_search('example_user')
userid = dir(usr[0]) 
allmed = api.user_recent_media(user_id=userid, count=10, min_id=0, max_id=10000000000000000000000000000000000)
print allmed
```

However, I get the following error:

```
raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.', status_code=response['status'])
instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

What seems to be wrong with my code?

Comment: Check out the github issues, this looks like a problem with a library and out of date documentation.
https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/issues/180

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the user `Twitter ID` as the `user_id` (not username/handle name/screen_name), access it with `user.id`.

```
usr = api.user_search('example_user')
api.user_recent_media(user_id=usr[0].id)
```

I'm not sure why would you pass `dir(usr[0])` as `user_id`.